# Comparar todas as rows e columns de dois Df, atualizar e somar as diferenças ao final das rows e columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Possuo dois csv separados por tab. Ambos possuem o mesmo número de rows e columns. A primeira coluna `POS` possui os mesmos unique values nos dois df. As diferenças (ou não), ocorrem nos valores (strings) das colunas `col1:col4`.

Pensei em realizar uma query, algo como: `query = subset_pl(subset_pl.isin(subset_ad))`
e a partir disso continuar com o código, mas eu fiquei preso aí...

```
import pandas as pd

subset_ad = pd.read_csv('subset_ad.csv', sep='\t')
subset_ad.set_index('POS')
subset_ad

POS         col1    col2    col3    col4
28355991    A       A       A       A              
28356037    A       A       A       A              
28356130    A       A       A       A              
28356246    A       A       A       A   



subset_pl = pd.read_csv('subset_pl.csv', sep='\t')
subset_pl.set_index('POS')
subset_pl

POS         col1    col2    col3    col4
28355991    A       B       A       A            
28356037    B       B       B       A              
28356130    A       B       A       A              
28356246    A       A       B       A
```

O que eu pretendo conseguir é: comparar `subset_ad` com `subset_pl`, atualizar `subset_ad` com o valor de `subset_pl` mantendo o valor de `subset_ad` separados por `,` (A,B por exemplo), caso haja values diferentes e contar essas diferenças tanto em rows como em columns adicionando uma row e uma column a mais (`cont_col`, `cont_row`) para exibir a contagem das células que sofreram alterações...

O output seria algo como:

```
subset_ad

POS         col1    col2    col3    col4    cont_row
28355991    A       A,B     A       A       1       
28356037    A,B     A,B     A,B     A       3       
28356130    A       A,B     A       A       1       
28356246    A       A       A,B     A       1       
cont_col    1       3       2       0
```

Qualquer direcionamento será bem vindo!

Comment: Colega, sua pergunta não tá nada clara. Pra começar, os seus valores são strings no formato "x/x" em que parece que x sempre é `0`, `1` ou `.`. Como isso é comparado? É comparação de string mesmo? Se sim, qual foi a sua dificuldade? Em segundo lugar, essa coluna `soma_rows`, por exemplo, de onde vem esse valor? Ele é uma soma? Se sim, soma de que?! Por que no resultado final tem uma vírgula? Enfim, sugiro que você forneça um exemplo **simples** do seu problema, talvez com duas linhas e colunas, e explique detalhadamente. Se não ninguém consegue te ajudar.

Comment: Olá amigo. Segui sua sugestão e alterei o exemplo...A princípio todos os dados são do tipo string mesmo! Eu estava lendo aqui, e pensei se a opção `df.merge` não seria possível neste caso...De modo que ao mergir ele adicionaria os valores de `subset_pl` ao `subset_ad` apenas onde estes fossem diferentes como mostrado acima no output desejado em `subset_ad[1,1]`

Comment: Agora sim! :) Vou responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

1. Leia ambos os arquivos em DataFrame's diferentes.
2. Concatene os DataFrames diretamente, usando o operador `+`. Você pode incluir uma string com a vírgula no meio. Esse operador vai executar para cada "célula" da tabela.
3. Itere sobre as linhas e colunas contabilizando as diferenças. Onde não houver diferenças (e se desejar), unifique as letras em uma só.

Exemplo de código:

```
import pandas as pd

# Lê o primeiro arquivo
subset_ad = pd.read_csv('subset_ad.csv', sep='\t', index_col=False)
subset_ad = subset_ad.set_index('POS')

print('subset_ad:')
print('-' * 20)
print(subset_ad)
print('-' * 20)

# Lê o segundo arquivo
subset_pl = pd.read_csv('subset_pl.csv', sep='\t', index_col=False)
subset_pl = subset_pl.set_index('POS')

print('\n')
print('subset_pl:')
print('-' * 20)
print(subset_pl)
print('-' * 20)

# Concatena os arquivos separando o conteúdo por uma vírgula
df = subset_ad + ',' + subset_pl

# Adiciona a coluna e a linha de somatório
df['cont_row'] = [0 for _ in range(len(df))]
df.loc['cont_col'] = [0 for _ in df.columns[:-1]] + ['']

print('\n')
print('subset_ad + subset_pl:')
print('-' * 20)
print(df)
print('-' * 20)

# Contabiliza as diferenças (unificando a letra onde não houver diferença)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index != 'cont_col':
        for col in df.columns[:-1]:
            val = row[col]
            letters = val.split(',')
            if letters[0] == letters[1]:
                df.set_value(index, col, letters[0])
            else:
                cnt = df.loc[index]['cont_row']
                df.set_value(index, 'cont_row', cnt + 1)

                cnt = df.loc['cont_col'][col]
                df.set_value('cont_col', col, cnt + 1)

print('\n')
print('resultado final:')
print('-' * 20)
print(df)
print('-' * 20)
```

Resultado desse código:

```
subset_ad:
--------------------
         col1 col2 col3 col4
POS
28355991    A    A    A    A
28356037    A    A    A    A
28356130    A    A    A    A
28356246    A    A    A    A
--------------------


subset_pl:
--------------------
         col1 col2 col3 col4
POS
28355991    A    B    A    A
28356037    B    B    B    A
28356130    A    B    A    A
28356246    A    A    B    A
--------------------


subset_ad + subset_pl:
--------------------
         col1 col2 col3 col4 cont_row
POS
28355991  A,A  A,B  A,A  A,A        0
28356037  A,B  A,B  A,B  A,A        0
28356130  A,A  A,B  A,A  A,A        0
28356246  A,A  A,A  A,B  A,A        0
cont_col    0    0    0    0
--------------------


resultado final:
--------------------
         col1 col2 col3 col4 cont_row
POS
28355991    A  A,B    A    A        1
28356037  A,B  A,B  A,B    A        3
28356130    A  A,B    A    A        1
28356246    A    A  A,B    A        1
cont_col    1    3    2    0
--------------------
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Luiz! Apesar de querer a contabilização das rows e cols diferentes, a resposta sem esta etapa seria muito mais simples do que eu estava imaginando. Era só usar uma concatenação simples de `df = subset_ad + ',' + subset_pl`. Funcionou Perfeitamente!